# What is causing the syntax error in this case?

Tags: php, wordpress

So my class starts out like

```
final class MyWordPressSite
{

    const ROOTURL = 'http://mywebsite/mysubsite';
    const THEMEROOTURL = self::$ROOTURL . '/wp-content/themes/allytics_theme';

    function getRootUrl ( ) 
    {
        return self::ROOTURL;
    }
```

and the `.` in `self::$ROOTURL . '/wp-content/themes/mytheme';` is being flagged as

> Syntax error: Unexpected token '$ROOTURL'

Any idea why? Everything looks right to me. I installed a PHP syntax highlighter and it's possible that it is incorrectly flagging that dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

```
const THEMEROOTURL = self::$ROOTURL . '/wp-content/themes/allytics_theme';
```

Doesn't obey that restriction:

`self::$ROOTURL` doesn't exist, because that would be a static variable reference, not even a reference to your previously defined constant, which should be referenced instead as `self::ROOTURL`

And use of concatenation is an operation (not supported prior to PHP 5.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

You should use.

```
private static $ROOTURL = 'http://mywebsite/mysubsite';
```

Comment: Then it can be modified outside of the class

Comment: `private static ... ` then :P

Comment: User `private` instead of `public`.

Please refer the visibility here. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php